# Visual Studio error: The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly ... The file exists

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to build a solution with many projects, and I'm getting this error for a Windows Service project:

```
The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070050): The file exists. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070050)
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.NativeMethodsShared.InprocTracking.WriteContextTLogs(String intermediateDirectory, String tlogRootName)
   at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.FileTracker.WriteContextTLogs(String intermediateDirectory, String taskName)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, Boolean& taskResult)   ImportProcessorWindowsService
```

As suggested in [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034/visual-studio-error-the-generateresource-task-failed-unexpectedly), I tried deleting my .suo file, but that did not help.

I have been able to build this solution in the recent past. How do I fix this?

Comment: I just had this happen, and I'm not using TFS. Luckily, exiting and restarting VS2010 fixed the problem.

Comment: Admittedly not an answer to this specific question, but possibly helpful to people finding this question with VS2015.  I found that this error occurred using the $ character: http://pmichaels.net/2016/02/19/the-generateresource-task-failed-unexpectedly/

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I figured this out. It seems to have been caused by some files being marked Read Only in the obj/x86 folder.

Lovely how TFS likes to mark files as Read Only.

I deleted the contents of obj/x86 and the error went away.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Close VS, delete obj folder and re-open VS.

Comment: Thanks so much, you saved my time.:)

Comment: I didnt close and reopen VS, but deleted obj folder and the project is building like a charm

Comment: You can just clean and build. It will do the same but you won't need to close vs.

Comment: this actually solved my problem compiling with an error of `System.IO.PathTooLongException`

Answer (score 2):

I checked out (VSS) the obj folder in Solution Explorer and I got a dialog stating that a couple of files and or folders were missing and did I want to create them. I clicked OK and then rebuilt the project without errors.

Answer (score 2):

I had a .resx file that became corrupted.   I undid the change & pulled it from source control again to get the original copy restored.   That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In the more recent versions of Visual Studio it's quick and simple to use the clean and rebuild solution options available on the build toolbox

Comment: It will delete the compiled files in the same way as Mr Seibar already discovered and visual studio can re-compile them ready to debug once again providing there are no build issues.

Comment: Very nice little feature

Comment: the problem on this solution is that the `obj` folder is **not** deleted with `Rebuild Solution`. The deletion of the obj folder fixed the problem on my machine

Answer (score 0):

Run Visual Studio with as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I re-opened the same project with VS2013 instead of VS2010, so I successfully rebuild it (it creates a new file (*.v12.suo).
Then I back with VS2010 and finally all was ok.
Hope this helps