# MSBuild error MSB4018: The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: msbuild

I try to build a solution with MSBuild command line (on a clean machine) when only Build Tools 2015, .NET developer pack and .NET SDK are installed I get following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2718,5): error MSB4018: The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2718,5): error MSB4018: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2718,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResGenDependencies.GetResXFileInfo(String resxFile)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2718,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource.ShouldRebuildResgenOutputFile(String sourceFilePath, String outputFilePath)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2718,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource.GetResourcesToProcess(List`1& inputsToProcess, List`1& outputsToProcess, List`1& cachedOutputFiles)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2718,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource.Execute()
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2718,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2718,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

What's wrong?

Comment: MSBuild is now open source on GitHub so you might check the function to see where such an exception might raise. That should lead you to the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio error: The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly ... The file exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795926/visual-studio-error-the-generateresource-task-failed-unexpectedly-the-fil)

Answer (score 13):

Delete all build outputs and build again.
Suggested from Rainer Sigwald (https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/364).

Comment: I had the same problem. This is the answer that worked for me.

Comment: I got same problem when I move my working solution from different machine. I have delete project output folders bin and obj then build again and it works for me.